# Impossible to access an attribute ("nom") on a null variable

Tags: php, symfony, variables

I would like for each of my children, their picture appears but I have this error message that appears :

Impossible to access an attribute ("nom") on a null variable.

In my twig:

```
{% for eleve in eleves %}
  <div><img src="{{ asset('img/')~eleve.image.nom}}" alt="" width="200" height="200"></div> 
  <div>{{eleve.prenom}}</div>                             
{% endfor %}
```

In my controller :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/accueilPrincipal", name="accueilPrincipal")
*/
public function eleve(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    // On récupere tous les eleves
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Image::class);
    $repo2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Eleve::class);
    $images = $repo->findAll();
    $test = $repo2->findAll();

    $sexe = $this->getUser()->getSexe();
    $eleves = $this->getUser()->getElevestuteur1();
    $eleves2 = $this->getUser()->getElevestuteur2();

    $user = $this->getUser()->getNom();

    return $this->render('profile/accueilPrincipal.html.twig', [
        'eleves' => $eleves,
        'eleves2' => $eleves2,
        'user' => $user,
        'sexe' => $sexe,
        'images' => $images,
        'test' => $test,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for the Eleve class? Quite possibly the template should be `eleve.nom` instead of `eleve.image.nom`

Comment: hi,
I don't want the name of the student but his picture`.

Comment: Use the VarDumper component to see the content of your variables in the template (https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/debug.html). The error message indicates that one of your students has no image. You may either make sure all students have images in the first place or use Twig's default filter (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html).

Comment: Side note: You should build the path first and then pass it to the asset function (not appending some fragment to the result of the asset call). You may not use all its magic now (e.g. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-framework-assets-version) but it may save you troubles down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the `$eleves` variable, and it should be a lot clearer. `dump($eleves);die;` before the `return $this->render(...)` will show you what is actually there, instead of what you think *must* be there, but you don't quite know.

Comment: Only the last paragraph in this answer relates to the actual problem. (Not using a variable in a template does not need to bother the controller; Twig can access both arrays and objects with the same Syntax, so referring to arrays here while the code is clearly object-oriented is confusing; the "tuteur" is a tutor, so what makes you think the result is a URL?)